# Select text in medium-editor

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I'm using medium-editor, I have the following code:

```
    rangy.init();

    var HighlighterButton = MediumEditor.extensions.button.extend({
        name: 'highlighter',
        tagNames: ['mark'],
        contentDefault: '<b>H</b>',
        contentFA: '<i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>',
        aria: 'Highlight',
        action: 'highlight',

        init: function () {
            MediumEditor.extensions.button.prototype.init.call(this);
            this.classApplier = rangy.createClassApplier('highlight', {
                elementTagName: 'mark',
                normalize: true
            });
        },
        handleClick: function (event) {
            this.classApplier.toggleSelection();

            // Ensure the editor knows about an html change so watchers are notified
            // ie: <textarea> elements depend on the editableInput event to stay synchronized
            this.base.checkContentChanged();
        }
    });

    var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', {
            toolbar: {
                buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'highlighter']

            },
            buttonLabels: 'fontawesome',
            extensions: {
                'highlighter': new HighlighterButton()

            }
        });
```

As I do so that in the handleClick function I detect only the selected text in the editor, thanks for your response.

They can tell me how to place the functions and how they work: saveSelection (), restoresSelection (), etc.